# Attachment should be ther in the form and my email is working , But i want to send an email without attchment in the same form. So how to do that

Tags: vb.net, email, attachment

My email is working but needs to send without attachment. Everything is working properly. cannot delete the attachment. Sometimes need to send with attachment too.

```
    Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)
    smtpserver.Port = 587
    smtpserver.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    mail = New MailMessage
    mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox4.Text)
    mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    mail.Subject = TextBox2.Text
    mail.Body = TextBox3.Text
    Dim attach As New Attachment(TextBox6.Text)
    mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
        smtpserver.EnableSsl = True
    Try
        smtpserver.Send(mail)
        MsgBox("Email Sent")
    Catch ex As SmtpException
        MsgBox("Its an Error")
    End Try
```

Comment: If you don't need an attachment, don't execute the line `mail.Attachments.Add(attach)`

Answer (score 0):

If looks like your attachment is in TextBox6.Text.  If so, just check it contains something (or better still contains something valid) and only add the attachment if it does.

Something like this

```
    If Not String.IsNullorWhitepace(TextBox6.Text) Then
        Dim attach As New Attachment(TextBox6.Text)
        mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
    End If
```